# Bukkit - How to check if a player is attacking

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I check if a player is swinging a sword in a if() statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the PlayerInteractEvent and check if said player is holding a sword.

This example can be used for 1.9:

```
if (p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD)
```

For 1.8 and below you can simply use: `player.getItemInHand().getType()`

Make sure to check if the Action is LeftClickBlock or LeftClickAir(Attacking):
`if (e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_AIR && e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntityDamageByEntityEvent` as well, if you specifically need to know when player is attacking something.

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event)
{
    if (event.getDamager() instanceof Player){
       //player is attacking someone
       .......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically check if a player was damaged by someone using a diamond sword, you can use

```
       @EventHandler
       public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {

        if (event.getDamager() instanceof Player && event.getEntity() instanceof Player) {

         Player attacker = (Player) event.getDamager();

         if (attacker.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD) {

          Player victim = (Player) event.getEntity();
          //Do something
          Bukkit.broadcastMessage(attacker.getName() + " hit " + victim.getName() + " with a diamond sword!");

         }

        }

       }
```

This would check if a player was attacked by someone else using a diamond sword. In case you only want to detect if someone is hitting some entity with a diamond sword, leave the "victim" part/checks out.